# Django join query using foreignkey

Tags: django, join

MY model:

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Locations(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Regions, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

```
select locations.name,regions.region_name
from locations 
inner join regions on locations.region_id = regions.id
order by locations.name;
```

How to do this query in Django ?
I want to show countryname-regionname in select tag like pune-india

Comment: Share your models.

Comment: Added models.py pls check this

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this with:

```
mylocation.region.region_name
```

with `mylocation` a `Location` object, but this will make an extra query to fetch the region.

You can boost efficiency with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
locations = Location.objects.select_related('region').order_by('name')
```

In that case the data for the `.region` will be loaded in the same query.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Location` instead of <s>`Locations`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally model fields have no prefix with the name of the model. This makes
> queries longer to read, and often want uses inheritance of (abstract) models to
> inherit fields, so using a prefix would make it less reusable. Therefore it
> might be better to rename your field <s>`region_name`</s> to `name`.

Comment: Thank you.I want to show Location-region format in front end in v-select .How could I achieve it?

Comment: <v-flex ml-2  md2>
          <v-select :style="{padding:0,height:'30px'}"
              v-model="location_id"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="id"
              :items="locations"
              label="Location Filter"
              @change="getProjectsAndVehiclesFilter"
              required
              :single-line = true
              >
          </v-select>
        </v-flex>